# What is the unit of time in the following code?

Tags: python, pytorch

The following code shows inference time of the network. However, I am not sure what the unit of time is. Read through the documentation [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html), but still confused

```
####This code is for measuring performance such as inference time, FLOPs, Parameters etc...
    dummy_input = torch.randn(1, 3, 256, 256).cuda()

    macs, params = profile(model, inputs=(dummy_input,), verbose=0)
    macs, params = clever_format([macs, params], "%.3f")
    name = "SegDepthWithTwoDecoders"
    print("<" * 50, name)
    print("Flops:", macs)
    print("Parameters:", params)

    starter, ender = torch.cuda.Event(enable_timing=True), torch.cuda.Event(
        enable_timing=True
    )

    repetitions = 300
    timings = np.zeros((repetitions, 1))

    for _ in range(10):
        _ = model(dummy_input)

    # MEASURE PERFORMANCE
    with torch.no_grad():
        for rep in range(repetitions):
            starter.record()
            _ = model(dummy_input)
            ender.record()
            # WAIT FOR GPU SYNC
            torch.cuda.synchronize()
            curr_time = starter.elapsed_time(ender)
            timings[rep] = curr_time
    print("time :", np.average(timings))        
    ###This is where the code ends for measuring the performance
```

This is what the output looks like

```
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< SegDepthWithTwoDecoders
Flops: 1.924G
Parameters: 3.986M
time : 12.67153577486674
```

Comment: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cuda.Event.html#torch.cuda.Event.elapsed_time

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of `Event.elapsed_time()`
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cuda.Event.html

> Returns the time elapsed in **milliseconds** after the event was recorded
> and before the end_event was recorded.